# Where did the question about the first bug move, or do I remember wrong?

Tags: support, deletion

My impression is, that we once had a question, whether it is true, that the first bug in history was a real bug (the animal), but I can't find it.

To be sure, I searched on Programmers too, but there it isn't too. Was it deleted?

I'm asking, because I found a fine answer, with a picture of the bug himself, and further information.

Comment: It has been (re-)asked recently: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10298/did-the-computing-term-bug-come-from-a-moth-stuck-in-a-computer

Comment: Thanks, @Oddthinking. But too late. I deleted the bookmark long ago. Meanwhile I pretty much lost my interest in this anticritical, unskeptical website. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a deleted post here on Skeptics, I searched for `deleted:1 bug` and only got results for other posts, not the one you're looking for.

It could have been a comment, I don't think those are searched by the on-site search. Or it was on a completely different site.

Comment: Thanks very much. Maybe I read it elsewhere.